# Why do float calculation results differ in C and on my calculator?

Tags: c, floating-point-precision

I am working on a problem and my results returned by C program are not as good as returned by a simple calculator, not equally precise to be precise.
On my calculator, when I divide 2000008 by 3, I get 666669.333333
But in my C program, I am getting 666669.312500
This is what I'm doing-

```
printf("%f\n",2000008/(float)3);
```

Why are results different? What should i do to get the result same as that of calculator? I tried double but then it returns result in a different format. Do I need to go through conversion and all? Please help.

Comment: Though I just found a shortcut. I used (double)3 instead of (float)3 and left %f as it is. Though this worked, but I would really like to know why this happened and what are the alternatives? I don't think what i did is proper method.

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/  It's an easier read than the Goldberg paper, and will likely give you most of what you need to know.

Comment: You're lucky since 2000008 can be represented correctly by float. But many 7-digit numbers cannot be represented correctly since float can only be accurate to 6-7 decimal digits and if you use those numbers it'll introduce even more error. Try avoiding float as much as possible

Comment: alternative?? double??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html for an in-depth explanation.

In short, floating point numbers are approximations to the real numbers, and they have a limit on digits they can hold. With float, this limit is quite small, with doubles, it's more, but still not perfect.

Try

```
printf("%20.12lf\n",(double)2000008/(double)3);
```

and you'll see a better, but still not perfect result. What it boils down to is, you should never assume floating point numbers to be precise. They aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers take a fixed amount of memory and therefore have a limited precision. Limited precision means you can't represent all possible real numbers, and that in turn means that some calculations result in rounding errors. Use `double` instead of `float` to gain extra precision, but mind you that even a `double` can't represent everything even if it's enough for most practical purposes.

Gunthram summarizes it very well in his answer:

> What it boils down to is, you should never assume floating point numbers to be precise. They aren't.